# Arduino: How store values in a char array in one line then clear/empty a char array?

Tags: arrays, serial-port, char, arduino

I am attempting to write code that will store the command text between a { and } from the serial terminal.  So far I have:

```
byte index = 0; // Index into array; where to store the character
char cmdArr[10];

boolean startOfLine = false;
boolean endOfLine = false;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(38400);
}

void serialEvent()
{
  while (Serial.available())
  {
    char cmd = (char)Serial.read();

    if (cmd == '{')
    { 
      startOfLine = true;
    }

    if (cmd == '}')
    { 
      endOfLine = true;
      //cmdArr[index] = '\0'; //null terminate the C string; I'm not sure if this is needed
    }

    if (startOfLine && cmd != '{'  && cmd != '}')
    {
      cmdArr[index++] = cmd;
    }

    if (startOfLine && endOfLine)
    {
      int i;

      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
        //Do something with the command
      }

      startOfLine = false;
      endOfLine = false;
      break;
    }
  }
}

void loop()
{ 
}
```

I am able to iterate through cmdArr to print out the array values. Right now, for example, the command is getting stored like so: char cmdArr[10] = {'p', 'h', 'c', '\0'};  Is it possible to store the command like char cmdArr[10] = {"phc"};?  Also, how would I clear/empty that command to get ready for the next command?

**New code that seems to be working.  I resorted to using a String since it seemed like the easiest approach:**

```
String cmdData; //Store the complete command on one line to send to sensor board.

boolean startOfLine = false;
boolean endOfLine = false;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(38400);
  Serial3.begin(38400);
}

void serialEvent()
{
  while (Serial.available())
  {
    char cmd = (char)Serial.read();

    if (cmd == '{')
    { 
      startOfLine = true;
    }

    if (cmd == '}')
    { 
      endOfLine = true;
    }

    if (startOfLine && cmd != '{'  && cmd != '}')
    {
      //Serial.print("Send command");
      cmdData += cmd;
    }

    if (startOfLine && endOfLine)
    { 
      startOfLine = false;
      endOfLine = false;

      cmdData += '\r';

      Serial3.print(cmdData);

      cmdData = "";
    }
  }
}

void serialEvent3()
{
  char cmd3 = (char)Serial3.read();
  Serial.print(cmd3);
}

void loop()
{ 
}
```

Comment: `cmdArr[10] = "phc\0"` may work. Additionally, `cmdArr` can be used the same way as `&(cmdArr[0])`; both are of type `char*` which is as close to 'real' strings as you'll get in C. Operations working on strings, like `strcmp()`, will take that `char*` as input representing a 'string' variable.

Answer (score 1):

The cmdArr is a contiguous block of memory. In a sense the data is already stored there as "phc\0". You should be able to use cmdArr as a pointer to be able to print the data as a string instead of accessing characters one by one (you can also access characters one by one with pointers though). 
In your solution I don't think you need to clear the array ever. It is enough to set the index to 0 and make sure that when you wrote all the characters you terminate the string with \0 (what you are already doing). Strings in C are zero terminated. If you want to process the contents one by one in your loop you need to exit the loop if you encounter zero.